# How can I make an code that turns Off/On Users Location on MKmapView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, mkmapview

I'm working on a UI Switch where the User can turn Off Users Location.
I don't know how to write the code for that problem here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class Location_Switch_Controller: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var LocationSwitch: UISwitch!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func switchDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn {
            
        }
        else {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do it?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: *"... turn Off Users Location"* -- from your question, we have no idea what your app is doing with "Users Location"? Please review [ask].

Comment: I wanted to ask how to write a code that switches the location service of the user on and off. (Which the user can operate)
I'm sorry for the disagreements. Have a nice day.

Comment: Are you trying to disable Location Service on the **Device**? Or are you talking about showing/tracking the user's Location on the map view? If so, have you looked at the documentation for `showsUserLocation` and `setUserTrackingMode` here? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview

Comment: I'm trying to disable tracking the User's Location with a switch, wich the User can turn on and off. Hope this help's to understand:)